# Querying for terms with a Where clause in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

With RavenDB it's possible to get the terms of an index. This feature is documented [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/querying-for-terms)

Short question: is it somehow possible to get the terms filtered by an other field of the index?

Long question:
We are creating a knowledge base application, where our customers can store topics.

We built an index that is used for fulltext search and we are indexing over all topics. In the index we have 2 queryable properties: CompanyName, Query

```
public class SearchQueryResult
{
    public string Query { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class FullTextIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Topic, SearchQueryResult>
{
    public FullTextIndex()
    {
        Map = topics => from topic in topics
            from content in topic.Content
            select new
            {
                topic.CompanyName,
                Query = new object[]
                {
                    content.Title,
                    content.Description,
                    content.Article            
                }
            };

        Analyzers.Add(x => x.Query, typeof(OurCustomHtmlStandardAnalyzer).AssemblyQualifiedName);

        Indexes.Add(x => x.Query, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Stores.Add(x => x.Query, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

For the fulltext query I can then restrict the results to the according users company.

```
var results = _documentSession.Query<SearchQueryResult, FullTextIndex>()
            .Where(x => x.Query.StartsWith(input))
            .Where(x => x.CompanyName == "MyCompany")
            .OfType<Topic>()
            .ToList();
```

We want to add an AutoCompletion to our Search Input Field and for this we need to get the terms of the index (Query field)

The problem is, that the index does contain the terms for all companies, where we need only the terms for the current company.

In RavenDB Studio it is possible to get the stored, analyzed terms from the index:
[image]

--> How can i get these values with a query in my client code?

Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way to get the terms of an index. To get the terms the only function that the client api offers is documented [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/querying-for-terms).

So if you have to get the terms filtered by some property value you must move the where clause to the index definition.

If the value to be filtered is known upfront, you can use a static index definition class inheriting from `AbstractIndexCreationTask`

```
public class FullTextIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Topic, SearchQueryResult>
{
    public FullTextIndex()
    {
        Map = topics => from topic in topics
            where topic.CompanyName == "TheFirm"
            from content in topic.Content
            select new
            {
                topic.CompanyName,
                Query = new object[]
                {
                    content.Title,
                    content.Description,
                    content.Article            
                }
            };

        Analyzers.Add(x => x.Query, typeof(OurCustomHtmlStandardAnalyzer).AssemblyQualifiedName);

        Indexes.Add(x => x.Query, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Stores.Add(x => x.Query, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Note the where clause in the Map part.

If you don't know the filtering value upfront for example if you have multiple companies, you can build a dedicated index for each company. So you end up with some static indexes like FullTextIndexForXXXX, FullTextIndexForYYYY etc.

This Indexes then contain the filtering and you can use the provided GetTerms function of the RavenDB Client api to get the terms.

The index definition(s) must  me built dynamically.
I am using a IndexFactory to create the indexes. 
(Must be called at application start)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Raven.Abstractions.Indexing;
using Raven.Client;

namespace MyNamespace.Data.Index.FullTextIndex
{
    public static class FullTextIndexFactory
    {
        public static void CreateFullTextIndexes(IDocumentStore documentStore)
        {
            try
            {
                var companies = GetCompanies(documentStore);

                foreach (var company in companies)
                {                   
                    var indexName = "FullTextIndexFor" + company.Name;

                    var indexDefinition = CreateIndexDefinition(documentStore, company);
                    var existingIndexDefinition = documentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetIndex(indexName);
                    if (existingIndexDefinition == null)
                    {
                        CreateIndex(documentStore, indexDefinition, indexName);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (existingIndexDefinition.Equals(indexDefinition))
                        continue;

                    UpdateIndex(documentStore, indexDefinition, indexName);                
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // do something with the exception
            }
        }

        public static void CreateIndex(IDocumentStore documentStore, IndexDefinition indexDefinition, string indexName)
        {
            documentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutIndex(indexName, indexDefinition);
        }

        public static void UpdateIndex(IDocumentStore documentStore, IndexDefinition indexDefinition, string indexName)
        {
            documentStore.DatabaseCommands.DeleteIndex(indexName);
            CreateIndex(documentStore, indexDefinition, indexName);
        }

        public static IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition(IDocumentStore documentStore, Company company)
        {
            var indexDefinition = new IndexDefinition();

            var mapBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("docs.Topics.SelectMany(topic => topic.Content, (topic, content) => new");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("{");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("    topic = topic,");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("    content = content");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("})");
            mapBuilder.AppendFormat(".Where(this0 => this0.topic.CompanyName == \"{0}\")", company.Name);
            mapBuilder.AppendLine(".Select(this0 => new ");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("{");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("    CompanyName = this0.topic.CompanyName,");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("    Query = new object[]");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("    {");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("       this0.content.Value.Title,");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("       this0.content.Value.Description,");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("       this0.content.Value.Article");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("    },");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("    PublishStartDate = this0.topic.PublishStartDate,");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("    PublishEndDate = this0.topic.PublishEndDate,");
            mapBuilder.AppendLine("})");

            var map = mapBuilder.ToString();
            indexDefinition.Maps.Add(map);

            indexDefinition.Name = "FullTextIndexFor" + company.Name;

            var analyzerAssemblyQualifiedName = typeof(CustomFullTextAnalyzer).AssemblyQualifiedName;
            indexDefinition.Analyzers.Add("Query", analyzerAssemblyQualifiedName);

            indexDefinition.Stores.Add("Query", FieldStorage.Yes);

            return indexDefinition;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Company> GetCompanies(IDocumentStore documentStore)
        {
            using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                return session.Query<Company>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps if anyone has similar requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can query index something like this:

```
var results = _documentSession.Query<SearchQueryResult, FullTextIndex>()            
            .Where(x => x.CompanyName == "MyCompany")
            .Select(x=>x.Query)
            .ToList();
```

Then use foreach loop on results which will show your query properties

```
Title, Description, Article
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! That would work if I wanted all words withing the article. But we have a custom analyzer that strips away all html tags and stop words in the article.